# XMLHttpRequest onreadystatechange on IE8

Tags: javascript

I would like load php file with JavaScript for old browser. So i use XMLHttpRequest for get my file, but `onreadystatechange` don't work on IE8 :(

This my code :

```
function getOldBrowserBlock () {

    var blockOldBrowser = document.getElementById('js-old-browser'),
        filePath = '/wp-content/themes/bla/includes/alert-ie.php',
        x;

    if (XMLHttpRequest) {
        x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        x = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }

    // On charge le fichier
    x.open('GET', filePath, false);

    x.send();

    /**
    * Description for onreadystatechange
    * @private
    * @method onreadystatechange
    * @return {Object} description
    */
    x.onreadystatechange = function () {

        alert('this dont work on IE8');

        if (x.readyState == 4) {

            // Si le fichier est chargé
            if (x.status == 200) {


                // On affiche le message
                blockOldBrowser.innerHTML = x.responseText;
            }

        }

    };

}
```

Do you have idea ?

Thak you !

Comment: Try setting `onreadystatechange` before doing the `send` call

Comment: I would be very confused if that worked on any browser. You are using `false` as a third parameter to open which will make the request synchronous, in which case the readystate change callback will never be called rather the send statement will be blocking.

Comment: I've tryed to add send() after my onreadystatechange, but no result and add true for asynchrone

Comment: have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Can you please update your question with the changed code?

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the similar issue, first thing try to set `onreadystatechange` before the send. Refer to [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_7/xmlhttponreadystatechange-not-working-in-internet/e5aebea9-b1b3-48da-87f6-8c44e2731270?auth=1) post, it worked in my case.

Comment: I've tryed to add send() after my onreadystatechange, but no result.